# How can I write Python print( statement, end=' ') in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to add a space after `console.log` in JavaScript, not new line. Like in Python:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: what happen when you use console.log(i+' ');

Comment: No I didn't check that. Will it print as same?

Answer (score -4):

```
console.log(i + ' ')
```

This will print a string `i` and a space after.

Comment: ...and *then* a newline. `end=' '` in Python 3.x suppresses the line feed.

Comment: `print` does not log to the console in JavaScript.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding the question.  It looks to me like OP wants to console.log a string followed by a single space.

Comment: But crucially *"not new line"*

Comment: ah. I didn't realize JS did this by default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I followed the original question link, but didn't cracked it still. Can you please help me!

Comment: Ok I got it now. The desired thing is process.stdout.write(i + " "). Thanks all.